# How to check the authenticity of a domain?

Tags: security, domain

I have received a mail from `xxxxx@yahoo-inc.com`.

Is there any way I can check if this domain is owned by Yahoo, or by a scammer?

nslookup returns different results for `yahoo.com` and `yahoo-inc.com`.

WHOIS records for `yahoo-inc.com` don't seem to exist.

Comment: Thanks!  ( but do you Know this yourself, or is it only from Yahoo answers? --  Since I have found Yahoo Answers to be an unreliable source oftem)

Comment: Yes, sorry to lead you to believe that "Answers" was my only source.  I have gotten emails from `yahoo-account-services-us@cc.yahoo-inc.com` regarding my account, and they have been legitimate.

Comment: http://security.yahoo.com/article.html?aid=2006102502 is a more reliable source, scroll down to the paragraph below the graphic.

Comment: ok..  That seems to be a reliable source.  Can you post your answer as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Yahoo's [security page](http://security.yahoo.com/article.html?aid=2006102502) (emphasis mine):

> 1. Unofficial "From" address: Look out for a sender's email address that is similar to, but not the same as, a company's official email address. Fraudsters often sign up for free email accounts with company names in them (such as "ysmallbusiness@yahoo.com"). These email addresses are meant to fool you. **Official email from Yahoo! always comes from an "@yahoo-inc.com" email address**.
>
> Note: Fraudsters can forge the "From" address to look like a legitimate corporate address (like "@yahoo-inc.com"). Because of this, the "From" address is just one factor to consider when deciding if an email is trustworthy.

I have personally received emails from `yahoo-account-services-us@cc.yahoo-inc.com` when it was necessary for them to contact me about my account.  As the above note says, though, someone could still spoof this address like any other, so keep an eye out.  You can probably contact Yahoo's corporate office, via [this form](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/edit/forms_index.html) to verify that an email is legit.

Answer (score 2):

To check to whom a domain name is registered to you can always use the [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) service.

Most website on which you can register a domain name will offer a WHOIS search. For example you can check [godaddy whois result](http://who.godaddy.com/whois.aspx?domain=yahoo-inc.com&prog_id=GoDaddy) and see that the domain is registered to Yahoo.

There are lots lots of other WHOIS search providers that do find yahoo-inc.com::

http://www.networksolutions.com/whois-search/yahoo-inc.com

http://domains.whois.com/domain.php?action=whois  -- You need to enter yahoo-inc.com manually

and more......

Comment: @jonsca - Yes he did but i did the same search and provided results that do find yahoo-inc.com